# T-SQL vlookup with fake calendar table?

Tags: t-sql

I am rather new in T-SQL and I have to create a view, where the output will be as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrt63.png)

But my sales table doesn't have any data about sales in February and May for customer ABC and no data in January for customer XYZ, but I really want to have 0 for these months. How to do it in T-SQL?

Comment: For info on how to improve your question see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBo0.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is great question about a very important topic that, even many experienced developers need to touch up on. Being "relatively new at SQL" I wont just offer a solution, I'll explain the key concepts involved.

### The Auxiliary Table Numbers

First lets learn about what a tally table, aka numbers table is all about.

What does this do?

```
SELECT N = 1 ;
```

It returns the number 1.

```
N
-----
1
```

How about this?

```
SELECT N = 1 FROM (VALUES(0)) AS e(N);
```

Same thing:

```
N
-----
1
```

What does this return?

```
SELECT N = 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS e(n);
```

Here I'm leveraging the `VALUES` table constructer which allows for a list of values to be treated like a view. This returns:

```
N
-------
1
1
1
1
1
```

We don't need the ones, we need the rows. This will make more sense in a moment. Now, what does this do?

```
WITH e(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS e(n))
SELECT N = 1 FROM e e1;
```

It returns the same thing, five 1's, but I've wrapped the code into a `CTE` named ***e***. Think of CTEs as inline unnamed views that you can reference multiple times. Now lets CROSS JOIN ***e*** to itself. This returns for 25 dummy rows (5*5).

```
WITH e(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS e(n))
SELECT N = 1 FROM e e1, e e2;
```

Next we leverage `ROW_NUMBER()` over our set of dummy values.

```
WITH E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS e(n))
SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) FROM E1, E1 a;
```

**Returns (truncated for brevity):**

```
N
--------------------
1
2
3
...
24
25
```

**Using as an auxiliary numbers table**
@OneToTen is a table with random numbers 1 to 10. I need to count how many there are, returning 0 when there aren't any. NOTE MY COMMENTS:

```
;--== 2. Simple Use Case - Counting all numbers, including missing ones (missing = 0)
DECLARE @OneToTen TABLE (N INT);
INSERT  @OneToTen VALUES(1),(2),(2),(2),(4),(8),(8),(10),(10),(10);

WITH E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS e(n)),
 iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) FROM E1, E1 a)
SELECT    
  N       = i.N,
  Wrong   = COUNT(*),    -- WRONG!!! Don't do THIS, this counts ALL rows returned
  Correct = COUNT(t.N)   -- Correct, this counts numbers from @OneToTen AKA "t.N"
FROM      iTally    AS i -- Aux Table of numbers
LEFT JOIN @OneToTen AS t -- Table to evaluate
  ON      i.N  = t.N     -- LEFT JOIN @OneToTen numbers to our Aux table of numbers
WHERE     i.N <= 10      -- We only need the numbers 1 to 10
GROUP BY  i.N;           -- Group by with no Sort!!!
```

**This returns:**

```
N     Wrong       Correct
----- ----------- -----------
1     1           1
2     3           3
3     1           0
4     1           1
5     1           0
6     1           0
7     1           0
8     2           2
9     1           0
10    3           3
```

Note that I show you the wrong and right way to do this. Note how COUNT(*) is wrong for this, you need COUNT(whatever you are counting).

### Auxiliary table of Dates (AKA calendar table)

My we use our numbers table to create a calendar table.

```
;--== 3. Auxilliary Month/Year Calendar Table
DECLARE @Start DATE = '20191001',
        @End   DATE = '20200301';

WITH E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS e(n)),
 iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) FROM E1, E1 a)
SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(MONTH,@Start,@End)+1)
  TheDate        = f.Dt,
  TheYear        = YEAR(f.Dt),
  TheMonth       = MONTH(f.Dt),
  TheWeekday     = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,f.Dt),
  DayOfTheYear   = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,f.Dt),
  LastDayOfMonth = EOMONTH(f.Dt)
  FROM         iTally AS i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MONTH, i.N-1, @Start))) AS f(Dt)
```

**This returns:**

```
TheDate    TheYear     TheMonth    TheWeekday  DayOfTheYear LastDayOfMonth
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------ --------------
2019-10-01 2019        10          3           274          2019-10-31
2019-11-01 2019        11          6           305          2019-11-30
2019-12-01 2019        12          1           335          2019-12-31
2020-01-01 2020        1           4           1            2020-01-31
2020-02-01 2020        2           7           32           2020-02-29
2020-03-01 2020        3           1           61           2020-03-31
```

You will only need the YEAR and MONTH.

### The Auxiliary Customer table

Because you are performing aggregations (SUM,COUNT,etc.) against multiple customers we will also need an Auxiliary table of customers, more commonly known as a lookup or *dimension*.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
;--== Sample Data
DECLARE @sale TABLE
(
  Customer  VARCHAR(10),
  SaleYear  INT,
  SaleMonth TINYINT,
  SaleAmt   DECIMAL(19,2),
  INDEX idx_cust(Customer)
);

INSERT @sale 
VALUES('ABC',2019,12,410),('ABC',2020,1,668),('ABC',2020,1,50),  ('ABC',2020,3,250),
      ('CDF',2019,10,200),('CDF',2019,11,198),('CDF',2020,1,333),('CDF',2020,2,5000),
      ('CDF',2020,2,325),('CDF',2020,3,1105),('FRED',2018,11,1105);
```

**Distinct list of customers for an "Auxilliary Table of Customers"**

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Customer FROM @sale AS s;
```

For my sample data we get:

```
Customer
----------
ABC
CDF
FRED
```

### Putting it all together

Here I'm going to:

1. Create a numbers table
2. Use my numbers table to create a calendar table
3. Create an auxiliary Customer table from @sale
4. `CROSS JOIN` (combine) both tables for a "junk dimension"
5. `LEFT JOIN` our sales data to our calendar/customer auxiliary tables/junk dimension
6. Group by the auxiliary table values

**SOLUTION:**

```
;--==== SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @sale TABLE
(
  Customer  VARCHAR(10),
  SaleYear  INT,
  SaleMonth TINYINT,
  SaleAmt   DECIMAL(19,2),
  INDEX idx_cust(Customer)
);

INSERT @sale 
VALUES('ABC',2019,12,410),('ABC',2020,1,668),('ABC',2020,1,50),  ('ABC',2020,3,250),
      ('CDF',2019,10,200),('CDF',2019,11,198),('CDF',2020,1,333),('CDF',2020,2,5000),
      ('CDF',2020,2,325),('CDF',2020,3,1105),('FRED',2018,11,1105);

;--==== START/END DATEs
DECLARE @Start DATE = '20191001',
        @End   DATE = '20200301';

;--==== FINAL SOLUTION
WITH     -- 6.1. Auxilliary Table of numbers:
E1(N)     AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS e(n)),
iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) FROM E1, E1 a),
         -- 6.2. Use numbers table to create an "Auxilliary Date Table" (Calendar Table):
MonthYear(SaleYear,SaleMonth) AS
(
  SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(MONTH,@Start,@End)+1) YEAR(f.Dt), MONTH(f.Dt)
  FROM         iTally AS i
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MONTH, i.N-1, @Start))) AS f(Dt)
)
SELECT
  Customer  = cust.Customer,
  MonthYear = CONCAT(cal.SaleYear,'-',cal.SaleMonth),
  Sales     = ISNULL(SUM(s.SaleAmt),0)
         -- Auxilliary Table of Customers
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT s.Customer FROM @sale AS s) AS cust -- 6.3. Aux Customer Table
CROSS JOIN MonthYear AS cal -- 6.4. Cross join to create Calendar/Customer Junk Dimension
LEFT JOIN  @sale     AS s   -- 6.5. Join @sale to Junk Dimension on Year,Month and Customer
  ON       s.SaleYear  = cal.SaleYear
 AND       s.SaleMonth = cal.SaleMonth
 AND       s.Customer = cust.Customer
GROUP BY   cust.Customer, cal.SaleYear, cal.SaleMonth  -- 6.6. Group by Junk Dim values
ORDER BY   cust.Customer, cal.SaleYear, cal.SaleMonth; -- Order by not required
```

**RESULTS:**

```
Customer   MonthYear    Sales
---------- ------------ ------------
ABC        2019-10      0.00
ABC        2019-11      0.00
ABC        2019-12      410.00
ABC        2020-1       718.00
ABC        2020-2       0.00
ABC        2020-3       250.00
CDF        2019-10      200.00
CDF        2019-11      198.00
CDF        2019-12      0.00
CDF        2020-1       333.00
CDF        2020-2       5325.00
CDF        2020-3       1105.00
FRED       2019-10      0.00
FRED       2019-11      0.00
FRED       2019-12      0.00
FRED       2020-1       0.00
FRED       2020-2       0.00
FRED       2020-3       0.00
```